# How to keep track of a list of values associated to an HTML input text (dynamically created)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page in which almost all of the controls are created dynamically.

When I send the page I have no problem retrieving the data from those controls.
The problem comes when I have to retrieve the data of the "returns"(see buttons inside the blue frames), because since they are not inside any control I have to use an array to keep track of them.
[image]

This is the pop-up that is used to enter the returns for each **expression** (IF,ELSE IF,ELSE)[image]

My question is, what would you do if you had to keep track of those returns??
Would you create an js array of returns for every **expression**(IF,ELSE IF,ELSE) knowing that you would have to create arrays of arrays since each **structure** can have several instructions,which in turn can have several **expression**, which in turn can have several returns?? What would you do to keep the solution as simple as possible, considering that the only thing I don't have inside controls is the **returns**.

At present I'm using the js array approach but , I have to do a lot of things so that when I remove a **structure** of all the **returns** associated with the **expressions** inside that structure, get removed too.

## EDIT:

==============

The code I use to create all the controls in my page is too large to be posted it here, but here's an image showing the structure of the js array I use to store all the returns for each expresion(IF,ELSE IF,ELSE) and that I later submit as a json object.

Considering that structure, do you think it would be possible to simplified that structure so that **while I am still editing the page I only have to have the returns in a array**??

To make a long story short, I want to create the whole structure shown in the image just before I summit the form, NOT while I'm still editing the page.

Just a couple of extra things to consider:

- structures : Structure #1,Structure #2
- instructions: All the frames with a dropdown list showing "Multiple IF"
- expressions : All the IF's,ELSE IF's and ELSE's

==============

[image]

P.S. I'm not asking for any working code, I only want to hear your suggestions of what you would you do if you had to deal with a situation like the one described above.

Comment: Your question is really well explained, yet I can't help but feel even a *little* bit of the code might explain it a little better...

Comment: You say you're already using an _Array_ for it, why not just convert to _JSON_ and _POST_ in a hidden field at submission time?

Comment: @RGraham I have edited my question to add a image showing the structure of my current array, do you think you could take a look a it ???

Comment: @PaulS. Please see my question now.I try to describe the complexity of my structure a little more in detail. I hope you undestand now why I only want to have this whole structure just before I summit the form. Having only a "return" array while I'm editing.

Comment: You could use an object with idControl values as the keys, each key pointing to an array with the corresponding return values for the expressions. Not sure how much that would simplify your code though.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sorry,but do you think you could explain you point a little more in detail??

Comment: I was thinking on something like this: `{"exp1_i1_s3" : [Object, Object...], "exp2_i1_s3" : [Object, Object...]. "expN_iN_sN" : [...]}`, using the expression IDs as keys for an object.

Comment: Your comment was the answer to my question. But since it was not posted as an answer, I can not mark it as so

Answer (score 0):

Use the `form` element's `onsubmit` event.

```
<form action="" onsubmit="this['returns'].value = createReturnsArray();">
    <input type="hidden" name="returns" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, the function `createReturnsArray` is called and its return value send along with the form as `returns`. Of course, you would change all these things to suit your needs.